# Add a link to docker run

Tags: testing, docker

I am making a test file. I need to have a docker image and run it like this:
docker run www.google.com

Everytime that url changes, I need to pass it into a file inside the docker. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You need a custom docker image but this is definitely possible.

Let's say you want to execute the command "ping -c 3" and pass it the parameter you send in the command line.

You can build a custom image with the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM alpine:latest
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT /entrypoint.sh
```

The `entrypoint.sh` file contains the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
ping -c 3 "$WEBSITE"
```

Then, you have to build you image by running:

```
docker build -t pinger .
```

Now, you can run your image with this command:

```
docker run --rm -e WEBSITE=www.google.com pinger
```

By changing the value of the WEBSITE env variable in the latest step you can get what you requested.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it by adding this:
--env="url=test"
to the docker run, but I guess your way of doing it, is better. 
Thank you